Multidirectional propagation of biological neurons - could/should we recreate it e.g. with joint distribution neurons?
While ANNs are rather trained for unidirectional propagation, action potential propagation in biological neurons is symmetric e.g. ”it is not uncommon for axonal propagation of action potentials to happen in both directions” (from "Dynamics of signal propagation and collision in axons" PRE). As it is possible, they should be evolutionarily optimized for such multidirectional propagation, what might be crucial e.g. for learning (currently not well understood), consciousness (?)
Are there considered artificial neurons operating in multidirectional way?
One approach is somehow containing representation of joint distribution model e.g. $\rho(x,y,z)$, which allows to find conditional distributions in any direction by substituting some variables and normalizing - below is such inexpensive practical realization from https://arxiv.org/pdf/2405.05097 , allowing for many additional training approaches - could biology use some of them?
Are there different approaches? Research in this direction?
Is multidirectional propagation important/crucial for (e.g. learning of) biological neural networks?


1 This post contains many questions at once and is all over the place. 2 The image and the idea of a joint distribution neuron is not well explained. 3 The question in bold is much more a biology/neurology question than statistics. Yes, machine learning science can conceive of NNs with multidirectional propagation, for example in recurrent neural networks where connections between neurons exist that create loops, where output of a neuron becomes input to itselve, and where a clear hierarchical order in layers is disappearing. Is it biological? That's not a statistics question.

@SextusEmpiricus ,this is a very general question: biological neurons are superior especially in one-shot-learning, don't use our brute force backpropagtion, but have some different subtle multidirectional propagation. Is there any research in multidirectional ANNs? Joint distribution neurons is one approach - are there different considered?

I find it still confusing what you ask. In your post you write in bold "Is multidirectional propagation important/crucial for (e.g. learning of) biological neural networks?" which I interpret as a question for biologists. In your last comment you speak about ANNs.

You might reduce your question to just "Is there any research in multidirectional ANNs?", instead of the current nine question marks. But even then the question is still very broad. A simple yes and a single example (like recurrent neural networks) would already be an answer. It is not very clear when an answer would be acceptable or what would be a best answer.

@SextusEmpiricus, in ANNs we design artificial analogs of originally biological NN - these are multidisciplinary question: to better understand BNNs to catch up with ANNs. Indeed these is very broad question, I will give 50 points to the most valuable answer, e.g. pointing to good literature.

It is not only the awarding of the points. It is already that the question is confusing, and unclear what it's focus has. This post can have many different diverging answers handling entirely different questions. That makes it more like a discussion board than something for a q&a format. Possibly you could turn it into a community wiki, but also for that it is very broad.

@SextusEmpiricus the final is "Is multidirectional propagation important/crucial for (e.g. learning of) biological neural networks?" - basically yes or no question, preferably with elaboration, literature.

So "should we search for multidirectional ANNs to catch up with biology?" or "How to design them?" is not the question here?

And "could/should we recreate it e.g. with joint distribution neurons?" is neither? And if it is, how should we interpret the "e.g." part? Do you want to know about joint distribution neurons specifically or not?

These are all variations of that questions - if it is crucial for BNNs, we should consider it for ANNs.
